# Program does not terminate

Tags: c++, g++

In the following code, when run using GNU GCC v8.2.0, code does not terminate:

```
int main(void)
{
    /* code */
    int myArray[] = {2, 4};
    int otherArray[] = {777, 888};

    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = 0;
        cout << "myArray[" << i << "]=";
        cout << myArray[i] << endl;
        cout << "add: " << &myArray[i] << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
    {
        cout << "otherArray[" << i << "]=";
        cout << otherArray[i] << endl;
        cout << "add: " << &otherArray[i] << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
add:0x28ff24
myarray[2]=0
add:0x28ff28
myarray[0]=0
add:0x28ff20
myarray[1]=0
add:0x28ff24
myarray[2]=0
add:0x28ff28
myarray[0]=0
add:0x28ff20
myarray[1]=0
add:0x28ff24
myarray[2]=0
add:0x28ff28
myarray[0]=0
add:0x28ff20
myarray[1]=0
add:0x28ff24
myarray[2]=0
add:0x28ff28
myarray[0]=0
add:0x28ff20
myarray[1]^C
```

Comment: Your program has [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/7478597). `int myArray[] = {2, 4};` defines an `int[2]` but a few lines later you write elements with index 0 ... 3 (here: `for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = 0;`

Comment: You might be corrupting the stack when writing to `myArray[2]` and `myArray[3]`

Comment: @SHG is there any way to stop corruption of stack from these kinds of code. Also is this a defined behaviour?

Comment: Please, have a look at this: [SO: Accessing an array out of bounds gives no error, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1239938/7478597). This may help to understand your issue...

Comment: If you write array elements which you didn't allocate before (i.e. accessing elements behind end of array) you may write into memory of other variables or things which are stored there. This might be e.g. the storage of your index variable `i` in `for` loop. However, that's fully beyond your control. That's why the term undefined behavior is used (instead of e.g. a crash). The latter might happen - one possible behavior but it's simply not predictable. Instead, the consequence could be completely harmless and non-observable. It's just... undefined behavior.

Comment: I suggest using std::vector<int> instead of C arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
```

Replace the 4 in the 'for loop' by 2 like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
```

Since you're using a static array so it's better to specify the fixed size, but the most important is to be aware when you try to access the array by comparing the index being processed with the size of the array to avoid this behavior.

Comment: Yeah. Or `myArray` should be declared/defined with sufficient size. ;-)

Comment: Since you're using a static array so it's better to specify the fixed size, but the most important is to be aware when you try to access the array by comparing the index being processed with the size of the array to avoid this behavior.

Comment: @AbdelfettahBesbes even though I am accessing out off bound for myArray, shouldn't it stop by printing garbage values after 4 iterations?

Comment: @Scheff, Thanks)

Comment: @Vishalgupta, This is an undefined behavior which means the result is unpredictable during execution and it can be even different in every execution.

Comment: @Vishalgupta you are writing to memory, not just reading it. If you would be just reading, then it would most likely just output garbage or crash on invalid access, but because you write into memory, you will most likely overwrite some value which is important for other parts of code, causing completely weird behaviour. In this case the infinite loop is quite nice, with complex apps and large source similar bug often keeps silent until much later some completely different part of code starts to "act werid", these bugs are then difficult to find. (using valgrind and static analysis tools helps)

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking undefined behaviour by writing the indexes `0`-`3` of the 2 element array `myArray`.

As this is undefined behaviour there are no guarantees as to what is happening or what will happen if you run the code again in the future. A likely explanation for your observed behaviour is that when you write `myArray[2]` that is actually overwriting the value of `i` causing your loop to restart back at `0`.

The simple solution is to make `myArray` larger or change your for loop limit to `2`.

To detect this sort of behaviour use `std::array` instead and call the `at` function which has bounds checking and will throw an exception when you go outside the bounds of the array. e.g.:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    /* code */
    std::array< int, 2 > myArray = { 2, 4 };
    std::array< int, 2 > otherArray = { 777, 888 };

    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        myArray.at(i) = 0;
        std::cout << "myArray[" << i << "]=";
        std::cout << myArray[i] << "\n";
        std::cout << "add: " << &myArray.at(i) << "\n";
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "otherArray[" << i << "]=";
        std::cout << otherArray.at(i) << "\n";
        std::cout << "add: " << &otherArray.at(i) <<  "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`std::array` also has the bonus of a `size()` method which can make your code safer too:

```
    for(int i = 0; i<myArray.size(); i++)
    {
        myArray.at(i) = 0;
        std::cout << "myArray[" << i << "]=";
        std::cout << myArray[i] << "\n";
        std::cout << "add: " << &myArray.at(i) << "\n";
    }
```